# How to clone subsystems but with a different set of parameters in Simulink? Or: How to define local index variables for subsystems?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, simulink

My Simulink model will contain *(a lot of)* `n` identical subsystems, each defined by about 30 different predetermined parameters. Currently every time I duplicate a subsystem I need to modify the properties of every single block, consequently a lof of work with error-proneness. So my idea is to store corresponding parameters in a vector as follows:

```
parametersA = (parameterA1 , parameterA2 , ... , parameterAn);
...
parametersZ = (parameterZ1 , parameterZ2 , ... , parameterZn);
```

The values in the block properties will then be defined as `parametersA(2)` for subsystem #2 and `parametersA(n)` for the n-th subsystem. Or imagine every subsystem contains a PID-controller and the proportional gain `KP` needs to be defined. So the first subsystem will call `KP(1)` and the n-th `KP(n)`.

Hence my basic question is: how can I declare my index variable `n` within every subsystem, so every single block knows which element of the parameter vector to call?

An additional question would be: is it actually necessary at all to replicate my subsystems or could everything be done in one? Would that affect simulation time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at masking your subsystem and parameterising it with just one structure in the mask (see [Masking](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/masking.html) in the doc)? All the blocks underneath the mask would then be parameterised with fields of that structure. You could then have a cell array of structures that you use to parameterise each instance of the subsystem. In fact, the only parameter you may need for the mask is the index in the cell array, which is defined in your base workspace.

Comment: thanks, that was easy ;)  Do you see a way to access the subsystem easily by implementing a button "look under mask"? Because my model should be "used" by people with almost no experience in simulink, they need to look under the mask, but may not consider this option by right-clicking. I could mention it in the mask discription, but it should be as easy as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if the new Simulink editor allows to navigate under a masked subsystem using the model browser. It may also be possible to add a custom command to the model editor (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/adding-items-to-model-editor-menus.html) using open_system or hilite_system and point to a block underneath the mask.

Comment: Yes, the new Simulink editor (from 2012a on) shows a little arrow icon on the bottom left corner of every masked subsystem. Its quite intuitive to navigate by just clicking on the arrow.

Comment: @wrapped thanks, I thought that was the case, but couldn't find any reference of it online